# Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0, after updating ExpoKit from SDK 32 to SDK 33

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting bunch of errors in Android project, after updating ExpoKit project from SDK 32 to SDK 33.

I followed official guide for updating [ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit/#upgrading-expokit)

Here errors which I got:

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute data@scheme at manifestMerger6401876400338623003.xml requires a placeholder substitution  but no value for <appAuthRedirectScheme> is provided.


Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0

   > Could not find host.exp.exponent:expoview:33.0.4.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0

   > Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using [jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier)

```
npm i jetifier && npx jetify
```

Comment: Nice. I also posted some answer with some extras.

Answer (score 0):

[Jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier) node module should run android's official [jetifier-standalone](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) tool, which migrates support-library-dependent libraries to rely on the equivalent AndroidX packages instead.

Install node module `jetifier`:

```
yarn add -D jetifier
```

or

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier
```

You may run it

```
npx jetify
```

But you would better add `npx jetify` to your postinstall script on your `package.json``

```
  "name": "...",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "...",
    "android": "...",
    "ios": "...",
    "postinstall": "npx jetify"
  }
```